# How to write code for an expandable search bar, with a nav link that becomes a box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tumblr

I realise the question must be difficult to understand, but I really don't know how to explain what I'm trying to achieve in a few words. In short, I'm trying to customise a tumblr theme with a search function that looks like a link when one hovers over it, but when one clicks on it works like an expandable search box. Basically one that looks like this: [search box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1lSg.png)

Mine presently looks like this: [my search box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxNSb.png)

Here's the code:

```css
    .nav {
        font-family: 'Montserrat' 'Helvetica Neue' "Arial", serif;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: 400;
        padding: 16px 0;
        margin-bottom: 80px;
        font-size: 12px;
        text-align: center;
        border-bottom: 2px solid {color:Dividers};
    }

    .nav li {
        margin:0 10px;
        display: inline;
        line-height: 1;
    }

    .nav a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: {color:Nav}
        }
        
        
        
    .nav body {
     background: #fff;
     color: #666;
     font: 90%/180% 'Montserrat' 'Helvetica Neue' "Arial", serif;
     width: 800px;
     max-width: 96%;
     margin: 0 auto;
    }
    /*a {
     color: #69C;
     text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:hover {
     color: #F60;
    }*/
    h1 {
     font: 12px;
     line-height: 110%;
     color: #000;
    }
    p {
     margin: 0 0 20px;
    }


    input {
     outline: none;
    }
    input[type=search] {
 -webkit-appearance: textfield;
 -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
     font-family: inherit;
     font-size: 12px;
    }
    input::-webkit-search-decoration,
    input::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
     display: none; 
    }


    input[type=search] {
     background: #ededed url(https://static.tumblr.com/ftv85bp      /MIXmud4tx/search-icon.png) no-repeat 9px center;
     border: solid 1px #ccc;
     padding: 9px 10px 9px 32px;
     width: 55px;
 
 -webkit-border-radius: 10em;
 -moz-border-radius: 10em;
     border-radius: 10em;
 
 -webkit-transition: all .5s;
 -moz-transition: all .5s;
     transition: all .5s;
    }
    input[type=search]:focus {
     width: 130px;
     background-color: #fff;
     border-color: #66CC75;
 
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
     box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
    }


    input:-moz-placeholder {
     color: #999;
    }
    input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
     color: #999;
    }
```

```html
<div class="nav">
                {block:HasPages}
                {block:Pages}<li><a href="{URL}">{Label}</a></li>{block:Pages}
                {/block:HasPages}
                {block:AskEnabled}<li><a href="/ask">Ask</a></li>{/block:AskEnabled}
                  {block:SubmissionsEnabled}<li><a href="/submit">Submit</a></li>{/block:SubmissionsEnabled}
                  <li><a href="/archive">Archive</a></li>
                  <li><form style="display: inline-block" action='/search'class='search-form' id='nav-search' method='get'>
<input class='header-search-field' name='q' type='search' placeholder='Search'/></form>
</li>
</div>
```

I know the code is not the right one for what I'm trying to achieve, but it was the best I could do with my limited knowledge of coding.

I should mention that the search function at the moment doesn't work particularly well (i.e. it doesn't return all the results that it should, just a few tagged elements), but I'm not sure where the problem lies with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit your css file in order to achieve the effect you want.
In your case, the `input[type=search]` tag is the one that defines the appearance of your search box when it's not focused. In order to delete the border, you define the `border:none` property, otherwise it will default to the browser's value.

You may also not want the `background` property to make your searchbox gray with the magnifier icon.
The segment of your css file therefore changes to:

```
    input[type=search] {
      border: none;
      padding: 9px 10px 9px 32px;
      width: 55px;
      ...
    }
```

Snippet:

```css
    .nav {
        font-family: 'Montserrat' 'Helvetica Neue' "Arial", serif;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: 400;
        padding: 16px 0;
        margin-bottom: 80px;
        font-size: 12px;
        text-align: center;
        border-bottom: 2px solid {color:Dividers};
    }

    .nav li {
        margin:0 10px;
        display: inline;
        line-height: 1;
    }

    .nav a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: {color:Nav}
        }
        
        
        
    .nav body {
     background: #fff;
     color: #666;
     font: 90%/180% 'Montserrat' 'Helvetica Neue' "Arial", serif;
     width: 800px;
     max-width: 96%;
     margin: 0 auto;
    }
    /*a {
     color: #69C;
     text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:hover {
     color: #F60;
    }*/
    h1 {
     font: 12px;
     line-height: 110%;
     color: #000;
    }
    p {
     margin: 0 0 20px;
    }


    input {
     outline: none;
    }
    input[type=search] {
 -webkit-appearance: textfield;
 -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
     font-family: inherit;
     font-size: 12px;
    }
    input::-webkit-search-decoration,
    input::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
     display: none; 
    }


    input[type=search] {
     border: none;
     padding: 9px 10px 9px 32px;
     width: 55px;
 
 -webkit-border-radius: 10em;
 -moz-border-radius: 10em;
     border-radius: 10em;
 
 -webkit-transition: all .5s;
 -moz-transition: all .5s;
     transition: all .5s;
    }
    input[type=search]:focus {
     width: 130px;
     background-color: #fff;
     border-color: #66CC75;
 
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
     box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
    }


    input:-moz-placeholder {
     color: #999;
    }
    input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
     color: #999;
    }
```

```html
<div class="nav">
                {block:HasPages}
                {block:Pages}<li><a href="{URL}">{Label}</a></li>{block:Pages}
                {/block:HasPages}
                {block:AskEnabled}<li><a href="/ask">Ask</a></li>{/block:AskEnabled}
                  {block:SubmissionsEnabled}<li><a href="/submit">Submit</a></li>{/block:SubmissionsEnabled}
                  <li><a href="/archive">Archive</a></li>
                  <li><form style="display: inline-block" action='/search'class='search-form' id='nav-search' method='get'>
<input class='header-search-field' name='q' type='search' placeholder='Search'/></form>
</li>
</div>
```

If you wish to edit the background color when the searchbox is clicked, you must add the property to the `input[type=search]:focus` tag.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it really helped! Now it finally looks the way I want it, minus a little detail: the word "Search" is not on the very left of the bar, but slightly centered. Do you how I can change that?

Comment: Hi, you have to use the `padding` property in your css, which defines the spacing between your element border and your text. You can define each side independently (`padding-left`, `padding-right`, `padding-top`, `padding-bottom`), or by using the shorthand version: `padding: <top> <right> <bottom> <left>`. You can read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp). You should put it in either `input[type=search]` or `input[type=search]:focus` depending on your needs. If you wish to experiment with the values you can also use the Web Inspector of your web browser.